# is there a method to support chinese characters display in libreoffice calc sdk with c++?

Tags: c++, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

**Background**:
I'm developing a c++ application to write a .ods file(spreadsheet ) with libreoffice sdk(5.2) on linux machine(os is debian 9).
I have installed libreoffice sdk(5.2) package, and run the original c++ sdk example **SimpleBootstrap_cpp**(in sdk/examples/DevelopersGuide/ProfUNO/ dir) successfully after doing some essential configurations as the official document guides.

**Issue:**
The issue happens when I want to set a Chinese text to a cell. The characters display are messing in the UI interface. My code as following:

```
xCell = xSpreadsheet->getCellByPosition(1, 3);
xCell->setFormula(OUString("属性"));
//xCell->setFormula("属性"); //Also failed
```

I have searched OUString, didn't find a proper method to handle it. Anyone could give some information ?

[mess of show with chinese charachers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtZ0A.jpg)

Comment: have you tried with utf8 `setFormula(OUString("\xE5\xB1\x9E\xE6\x80\xA7"))` or utf16 `setFormula(OUString("\x5C5E\x6027"))` encoding?

Comment: There might be two factors responsible for: \* Encoding of the Chinese characters in your source file – it must be the same that libre office uses. (not sure which one, though, would assume UTF-8). \* The font used in libre office must support the Chinese characters. Though pretty old, the answer to [this question](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/41090/using-extended-character-sets-utf-8-and-thai/) in libre office forum might still apply, but you need to evaluate yourself.

Comment: @kritzikratzi I tried both, the first one's result same as the attached image before, the latter shows another special characters like "^'"...

Comment: ok. to think about it differently: what if you create a file with special chars in libreoffice, and then call `cout << xCell->getFormula()`?

Comment: @kritzikratzi @Aconcagua
Thank you. Inspired from  @kritzikratzi view, I found the output of "cout << xCell->getFormula()" is correct, and print it out is "0x5c5e, 0x6027". So I assume the OUString("\x5C5E\x6027") couldn't select a correct constructor. I investigated the doc at https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/cpp/ref/a00774.html, and test the following solutions are valid.
`sal_Unicode specialChars[3] = {0x5c5e, 0x6027, 0x0};
xCell->setFormula(OUString(specialChars));`
Or `std::string test("属性");
xCell->setFormula(OUString(test.c_str(), test.size(), RTL_TEXTENCODING_UTF8))`